# Trouble converting a bit of TSQL to LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Sorry about the vague title, not sure what verbage I should be using. I have a query similar to this (re-worked to save space):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Publishers p
    INNER JOIN Authors a
        ON p.AuthorID = a.AuthorID
    INNER JOIN Books b
        ON a.BookID = b.BookID
WHERE
    p.PublisherName = 'Foo'
ORDER BY
    b.PublicationDate DESC
```

I tried to re-write it as such:

```
var query =
    from publisher in ctx.Publishers
    from author in publisher.Authors
    from books in author.Books
    ...
```

but got the following error:

```
    Error   1   An expression of type 'Models.Books' is not allowed in a 
    subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type
    'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'.  Type inference failed in the
    call to 'SelectMany'.
```

I can re-write the LINQ to make it work by just joining the tables, as I would in SQL, but I thought I could accomplish what I want to do by their relationships - I'm just a bit confused why I can get publisher.Authors, but not author.Books.

Comment: You know, this actually works for me. Can you reveal the rest of the LINQ query? I sense the culprit is there.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have a relationship in your DB from Authors to Books.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var result = (from pItem in ctx.Publishers
join aItem in ctx.Authors on pItem.AuthorId equals aItem.AuthorId
join bItem in ctx.Books on pItem.BookId equals bItem.BookId
where pItem.PublisherName== "Foo"
select new {
// Fields you want to select
 }
).ToList();
```

i don't know exact relationship of the tables but you can an idea from this one.